# PostgreSQL user can not connect to server after changing password

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-3

I've met this with 4 roles I created:
After changing password for a user in pgAdmin III using the GUI (1), that user can not log in any more.
pgAdmin III show error message:

```
An error has occurred:

Error connecting to the server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "sam"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "sam"
```

My system: Postgresql 9.2 on Ubuntu 12.04

Is there any way to fix this?

(1): login with account postgres, right click user in Login Roles, go to tab 'Definition' and enter password

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's possible that you're being bitten by this **PgAdmin bug** ([changelog](http://www.pgadmin.org/development/changelog.php)):

> 2012-11-28 AV  1.16.1  Date picker controls returns a full timestamp
>   by 
>                          default, which can cause inadvertent date changes
>                          on jobs and role validty dates. Ignore the time part.

This bug has been seen to set password expiry dates far in the past, such as 1/1/1970. In this case the error message when trying to connect is no different than with a wrong password.

You can check these expiry dates with:

```
SELECT usename,valuntil FROM pg_user;
```

and if they're wrong, reset them with:

```
ALTER USER username VALID UNTIL 'infinity';
```

and upgrade pgAdmin.

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved the problem. Every time I reset a user password, pgAdmin set the valid until time to 01-01-1970 so that user cannot log in any more.

Comment: you got it! damn bugs

Comment: How exactly am I supposed to log in to psql??? 
That's the role I just updated.

Comment: @ericpeters0n: temporarily switch the authentication method to `trust` or `peer` in the `pg_hba.conf` file for this account.

Comment: Thanks, got it sorted. For those that come later, the "trust" means that: Once you've restarted postgres, you can run psql *without password authentication* iff you're a user of the same name as a privileged user (e.g. username 'postgres')... So, 'su - postgres psql' will allow you to log in and correct the password or valid date.

Answer (score 3):

The simple thing to do is to log in with psql or pgAdmin and

```
ALTER USER sam WITH PASSWORD 'new_password';
```

Now, if you cannot log in with a superuser account you can recover by altering the pg_hba.conf settings for this user and reload the config (sometimes I find this requires restarting the server, but am not sure why).

What you can do is add a line that allows you to log in using the ident (peer in 9.2) method (if you can use a local system account of the same name as the user) for local connections for the user, or (if that is not possible) set to "trust" (very temporarily!).  If using trust, set back as soon as possible, since this means "trust that the user is who he/she claims!" and consequently this setting is dangerous to leave enabled outside of immediate recovery needs.

Once you have logged in you can reset the password above.

Comment: Shouldn't pgAdmin perform just the same command?

Comment: (noting I said psql or pgAdmin.  What can I do to make it clearer?)

Comment: No-no, I just thought that changing passwords in the GUI does just the same.  If it does I can't imagine what could go wrong?

Comment: What could go wrong?  Typos in the password for starters....

Comment: Can't one simply set the password again once logged in as postgres?

Comment: Once I logged in as postgres and changed password for any user, that user can not log in any more. This happens with very simple password like '123', so it's not typo mistake.

Comment: how is the user logging in?  I suspect there is more going on than is apparent from the question.

Comment: I use that user account to log right into pgAdmin III and received error message as posted in the question

Answer (score 3):

For Windows variant - I too experienced this nasty bug because of pgAdmin for my Windows x64 install of version 9.2.  It left my production paralyzed.

In folder `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.2\data` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.**x**\data`, you'll find the **pg_hba.conf** text file.

Find the following lines:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

and change METHOD md5 to "trust" like this:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

From `Windows>Run` type "services.msc" and [enter]
find the right PostgreSQL instance and restart it.

Your DB security is now blown wide open!  Heed the warning to return it back to md5 after changing the user password expiry time to say year 2099 for all the relevant users.

Answer (score 1):

If you have not tried this already, review your pg_hba.conf file.  It will be named something like  /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/pg_hba.conf (Fedora 20); you may have to use 'find / -name pg_hba.conf' to locate it.

At the bottom of the file, change the 'METHOD' values to 'trust' for local testing (see postgres docs for full information).  Reboot the machine to ensure everything is started clean and the new params are read.

### Hopefully this will cure your woes.  It solved my problems on Fedora 20 with PostgreSQL 9.3.

UPDATE 2016-10-14:

On Ubuntu, the needed filename is `/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf`.  ***For local testing only***, modify it to look like this:

```
...
#
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
# local   all             all                                     peer
  local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
# host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
  host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
```

The two lines with METHOD "trust" are new.  They allow you to connect without a username/password.

When complete, you will need to restart the server via:

```
sudo systemctl restart postgresql
```

Comment: For the `pg_hba.conf` to take effect, you need only a reload, not a restart.  Furthermore, your suggestion looks incomplete as it is not clear how it would solve the issue in the end.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this same problem and it turned out that I had multiple users with the same name (differing cases). Once I merged the ownership and removed one, it was at least clear. Depending on the method of connection, the case was not necessarily transferred for authentication.

Answer (score 1):

`FATAL:  password authentication failed` can occur when you changed the user password remotely but the password authentication methods differs to the local one.

In this case the resolution is to edit the `pg_hba.conf` file and ensure consistent password authentication. For instance, 127.0.0.1 uses `scram-sha-256` and 192.168.1.2 uses `md5` then setting 127.0.0.1 to `md5` allows you to login again (after restarting the service).